# Java program to a web service\servlet

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets, jar

I've written a java program that handles certain http requests.

Now I'm asked to run this as a web service in IIS.

I've tried to export it as a jar and maybe run it like that...but I didn't succeed.

As far as I understood, I need to re-write the program as a web service or servlet and upload it this way to IIS.

My question is, how to do it (I'm using eclipse)? So far I managed to run a server but I never couldn't make my program to work. Can I have guidance please?

Comment: There's no shortcut. You need to read up and understand how to develop webservices. If you haven't worked with the Enterprise side of Java before, you have a lot to learn. So don't expect to finish it in a few days.

Comment: @Kayaman I'll be glad to receive a kind of resource to read and learn from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty old article but you can take a look [here](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-06-2000/jw-0616-iis.html?page=1)

For new IIS I'm not sure you can because Microsoft has it's own tech called .NET so I suppose it's better to use other server or use .NET

Also you can use [Tomcat connector for IIS](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html) which is filter with redirect